# Is Darth Vader really dead?

Tags: star-wars, darth-vader

I just finished the 3rd *Star Wars* movie, *Return of the Jedi*, and Darth Vader seemed to be dead. **Is this really true?**

Comment: If he's not, he's gonna be **really pissed off** about Luke burning him on a pyre

Comment: @Valorum I would assume [this](http://nooooooooooooooo.com/) would be his reaction to that

Comment: @Valorum Different franchise, but Doctor Who had the Master come back after being burnt on a pyre.

Comment: Well, his brain is in a jar on my desk, but for all I know he's out there practicing law somewhere.

Answer (score 12):

Well, yes. He's dead. he's a Force ghost at the end of ROTJ, and the two Force ghosts (Obi-Wan Kenobi and Yoda) that join him are most decidedly dead. [From the script](https://www.imsdb.com/scripts/Star-Wars-Return-of-the-Jedi.html) (emphasis mine)

> VADER:     (a whisper) Luke, help me take this mask off.
>
> LUKE: **But you'll die.**
>
> VADER: **Nothing can stop that now.** Just for once... let me look on you with my own eyes.
>
> Slowly, hesitantly, Luke removes the mask from his father's face. There
> beneath the scars is an elderly man. His eyes do not focus. But the
> dying man smiles at the sight before him.
>
> ANAKIN: (very weak) Now...go, my son. Leave me.
>
> LUKE: No. You're coming with me. I can't leave you here. I've got to save
> you.
>
> ANAKIN: You already have, Luke. You were right about me. Tell your sister...you were right.
>
> LUKE: Father...I won't leave you.
>
> **Darth Vader, Anakin Skywalker...Luke's father, dies.**
>
> A huge explosion rocks the docking bay. Slowly, Luke rises and, **half
> carrying, half dragging the body of his father**, stumbles toward a
> shuttle.

Luke later burns the body:

Comment: Well I know that. It was a pretty good movie wasnt it? So who was the next villian in the 4th Star Wars

Comment: @HomerSimpson - The “fourth Star Wars” is either *The Phantom Menace* (the villain is Darth Maul, with Sidious behind him) or *A New Hope* (Darth Vader, with Sidious behind him).

Comment: @HomerSimpson Well, *The Force Awakens* (Episode VII) features a guy named Kylo Ren and Snoke. All I'll say is Kylo Ren has a pretty neat souvenir from ROTJ...

Comment: @Adamant We can let someone new to the franchise just never know about episodes I - III, right? Give them the chance we never had?

Answer (score 5):

The *Star Wars* (canon) factbook is explicit on the state of Anakin/Darth after his iconic fight with Luke. **He's dead.**

> **With Anakin's death,** the last remnant of the Sith is no more, The man who helped destroy the Jedi Order has also ended the Sith, bringing balance to the Force as prophesied years ago.
>
> Anakin's armor is empty - **After his death he passes into the Force**, as Obi-Wan and Yoda did before him.

The new (and fully canon) [Disney junior novelisation](https://starwars.fandom.com/wiki/Return_of_the_Jedi:_Beware_the_Power_of_the_Dark_Side!) is also pretty blunt on the subject.

> ***When he looks back down, his father is dead.** But Luke keeps his promise. He will not leave his father. He stumbles toward the distant shuttle, staggering under the weight of this giant half-metal man who wrought so much evil.*
>
> *Leave him there, you want to shout to Luke. He’s the bad guy! The villain! Just leave him and get out of there before the whole Death Star blows up!*

As is the official Starwars.com [event gallery](https://www.starwars.com/films/star-wars-episode-6-return-of-the-jedi-story-gallery) for *Return of the Jedi*.

> *Realizing he cannot be saved, Vader asks Luke to remove his mask so that he may look upon his son with his own eyes. Luke insists that he must save him, but Vader — Anakin — affirms that he already has. **Luke's father dies as the Death Star begins to come apart around him.** Luke moves toward a shuttle, his only means of escape.*

---

We see him shortly afterwards as a Force ghost, a state that is incompatible with life.

[image: The 3 Force ghosts stand side by side smiling at the happy group off screen; from left to right we have Anakin (Hayden version with Sebastian's head), Yoda and Obi-Wan]

Comment: Dude I know I saw the Movie today.

Comment: @HomerSimpson - Well then.

Comment: I'm pretty sure I've upvoted every answer of yours I've read, but that force ghost image you've chosen is making it really hard in this case. Did you have no better options perhaps?

Comment: @ToddWilcox - Better now? [#Valorum's De-specialized Edition](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmy%27s_Despecialized_Edition)

Comment: +1 Some may complain about not having a freehand red circle around Anakin, but I'm not *that* petty.